# Send mail with nodejs

Tags: node.js, email, backend

For a school project I have to build a website and all the stuff...
I want to send an email when a certain button is pressed. For now  I used an gmail address for the server BUT it needs authentification and all. How can I bypass the authentification ? Are there some other STMP servers that do not require authentification so I send an email easily ?

Thanks guys !

Comment: are you looking for services like mailgun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **Nodemailer**

Its a npm module installed it and there you go.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'youremail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'yourpassword'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'youremail@gmail.com',
  to: 'myfriend@yahoo.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

Refer : https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_email.asp

Comment: I already have this code but thanks ! I was searching for another mail provider ( GMAIL doesn't like when I change IP address and all... )

Comment: @Ratatinator97 Not sure if this is still relevant, but regarding your above comment, you can use sendgrid for that https://sendgrid.com

Answer (score 0):

```js
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 587,
  secure: false,
  auth: {
    user: 'youremail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'here app password'
  }
});

const url = `http://localhost:3000/verify-email/${token}`;

const mailDetails = {
  from: 'Verify Your Email <youremail@gmail.com>',
  to: user.email, // Receiver email address
  subject: 'Registration - Verify Your Email',
  html: `<h2>${user.fullname} Thanks for registering on our site</h2>
    <h4>Please verfiy your mail to continue....</h4>
    <a href="${url}">Verfiy your email</a>`;
}

transporter.sendMail(mailDetails, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('An error occurred...', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Verification email was sent to your account');
  }
});
```