# Nodemailer with email-templates not sending email

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I'm using nodemailer with npm package email-templates. I'm not getting email. Template is working when i set preview:true. Getting error on console **Error: No recipients defined**.Why this error coming? Tried many things but nodemailer is sending empty email every time. Hope you understand my issue.

Error:

```
Error: No recipients defined
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (E:\testing\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:784:19)
    at SMTPConnection._setEnvelope (E:\testing\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:995:34)
    at SMTPConnection.send (E:\testing\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:615:14)
    at sendMessage (E:\testing\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-transport\index.js:227:28)
    at E:\testing\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-transport\index.js:285:25
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (E:\testing\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1537:9)
    at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (E:\testing\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:550:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (E:\testing\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:942:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (E:\testing\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:749:14)
    at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (E:\testing\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:195:44)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23) {
  code: 'EENVELOPE',
  command: 'API'
}
```

My directory structure:

```
├── app.js
└── emails
    └── forget-password
        ├── html.pug
        ├── subject.pug
```

Node mailer with template:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var generator = require('generate-password');

const Email = require('email-templates');

exports.sendNodeForgotPasswordMail = function (email, GeneratePassword) {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 587,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
            user: 'my_email',
            pass: 'my_password'
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }

    });

    const emailVar = new Email({
        message: {
            from: 'testing@gmail.com'
        },
        preview: true,
        send: true,
        transport: {
            jsonTransport: true
        }
    });

    emailVar.send({
        template: 'forget-password',
        message: {
            to: email
        },
        locals: {
            password: GeneratePassword
        }
    }) .then(res => {
        console.log('res.originalMessage', res.originalMessage)
    }).catch(console.error);


    return transporter.sendMail(emailVar, function (err, info) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            console.log(info);
    });
};
```

Html.pug:

```
p Your new password is: #{password}
```

subject.pug

```
= `Password reset request`
```

Comment: Message.from is defined but not "to" as error says you have not defined where you .sendMail to.

Comment: I tried it. Still not working.

Comment: Check if `email` var is defined.

Comment: Look at the example in documentation and see what is missing: https://nodemailer.com/about/ your code looks quite different

Comment: @Zydnar var email is defined and this documentation is for only nodemailer not for email-templates.

Comment: The rule is the same - template just fills some of these fields.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56183218/send-mail-with-nodejs/56183385#56183385 i think this would help you

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else is looking how to solve this, i manage to make it work based on @Irving Caarmal answer and the code is the following:

```
function sendTokenEmail(userEmail, token, templateName) {
  const email = new Email({
    message: {
      from: 'someemail@gmail.com',
    },
    preview: true,
    send: true,
    transport: {
      host: process.env.MAIL_HOST,
      port: process.env.MAIL_PORT,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.MAIL_USER,
        pass: process.env.MAIL_PASS,
      },
    },
  })

  return email
    .send({
      template: templateName,
      message: {
        to: userEmail,
      },
      locals: {
        token,
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log('res.originalMessage', res.originalMessage)
    })
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

the reason is that you dont need to require nodemailer instead of make your transporter with nodemailer you need to pass it in JSON like so.

```
exports.sendNodeForgotPasswordMail = function (email, GeneratePassword) {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 587,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
            user: 'my_email',
            pass: 'my_password'
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }

    });
```

becomes:

```
transport: {
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 587,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
            user: 'my_email',
            pass: 'my_password'
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }

    }
```

const Email = require('email-templates'); <-- with this is enough.

Answer (score 1):

if anyone has an issue with getting on their email address the mail generated you should add at the level with `send: true` also the option `preview: false` (PS: this worked for me) without having the `preview` set to `false` the email would not come even if the docs say:

`If you want to send emails in development or test environments, set options.send to true.`

**Example:**

```
const email = new Email({
  message: {
    from: process.env.SMTP_USER,
  },
  send: true,
  preview: false,
  transport: {
    host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
      auth: {
             user: process.env.SMTP_USER,
             pass: process.env.SMTP_PASS,
   },
  },
})

await email.send({
  template: 'template-of-choice', 
  message: {
    from: 'email-address'
  },
  locales: {}
})
```

**Hope it helps :)**